# Combinatoric Sequences

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series

I have a combinatorial problem that I think is related to sequences over an alphabet.

The situation is the following:
I have an alphabet of n symbols and I want to look at sequences that contain each symbol at most m times.

For which m and n exists a sequence s such that for each subset of the n symbols, there exists a substring of s containing exactly these symbols?

Example:
1) If I have 3 symbols A,B,C and K=2, there exists such a sequence:
ABCA, which contains (apart from the singleton subsets and the whole set) all subsets consisting of two symbols as substrings.
2) If K is unlimited, there exists such a sequence for each n since I can just spell out all subsets. The length of this string is exponential in n.

Has anyone encountered a problem like this?
I'd really appreciate pointers to related theories.

Comment: You might want to look at [De Bruijn sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence), which are sequences that contain each subsequence of symbols exactly once. In that case, the subsequences $BC$ and $CB$ both appear once.